# How to stop React Hooks component rerender on SOME state changes?

Tags: react-hooks, state

I have the following code:

```
const PlayArea = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState('foo')
  const [bar, setBar] = useState('bar')

  return <div>{bar}</div>
}
```

In my project, whenever I use  `setFoo`, the whole component re-renders, and I'm trying to prevent that. I only want the component to re-rerender when `bar` changes.

Is there anyway that I can keep the component from changing from using `setFoo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I can keep the component from changing from using
> setFoo ?

No. By design state variables work such that when you change them that component will rerender.

But If you don't want to rerender your component when you update that variable then why are you using a state variable? Use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes.
> Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render.